# Are colon ideals radical ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> If $I$, $J$ are ideals in $\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$, then is the colon ideal $I : J$ a radical ideal?

Someone is telling me this is true and I’ve been trying to prove it for awhile now and can’t see why it is...not sure if they’re just mistaken or if I’m not seeing something right in front of me.

Comment: Don't you need further assumptions? It's pretty easy to find a counterexample if $I$ isn't radical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, if $J$ is the entire ring, then $I:J=I$, which need not be radical.  Or if you want an example with proper ideals, $(x_1^3):(x_1)=(x_1^2)$ is not radical.

Comment: Thank you!...I probably should have tried to come up with a counter example myself but since it was my professor that posed this as true...

Comment: I haven't thought about it much, but I'm guessing this is true if $I$ is radical, and follows from primary decomposition.

Comment: @SteveD If $I$ is radical, then $r(I:J)=(I:r(J))$.